# reading Firestore subcollection as class object

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore

I'm working on android and I have to read a series of the document(I'm putting that into an array list). Each Document has a subcollection.

so as example.

```
CAR
- miles
- year
- color
- blablabla
-- MAINTENANCE (subcollection)
    -1
       date: 123
       km:  123456
    -2 
       date: 113132323
       km: 19493
```

I created a class of this document CAR and I'm able to read the field of the document using toObject(`myclass.class`). Now it's coming the fun part. I created a second Class called `MAINTENANCE`, including date and km.
inside the CAR class, I created a variable called `MAINTENANCE` that is an array list of Maintenance.

I'm able to read without any problem the CAR object but there's absolutely nothing in the Maintenance Array

Would you suggest me the right approach to read all data in a cycle? do I have to add a complete listener and run a second reading after the car has been read?

hello guys..  I edit due to make easier to understand as I think problem stays before......  I changed approach and digged down:   here is my DB:
[image]
Now...   if I simply try to read the subcollection document:

```
 Task<QuerySnapshot> TEST = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("CHARGEPOINT").document("12").collection("CONNECTORS").get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
            QuerySnapshot data = task.getResult();

            for(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot:task.getResult()){

                Log.d("DOCUMENTDATA", documentSnapshot.getData().toString());

            }

            Log.d("DATA", data.toString());

        }
    });
```

I got NO results....   the Querysnapshot is always empty.  I'm making an error but I really cannot understand what's wrong...

my Final Goal would be to have a helper class with a method "LoadStructure" that loads the data of both collection and subcollection ( ArrayList) and return, when completed, the ArrayList with all the data. CONNECTORS could be multiple this is the reason why I choose Arraylist

I already can read "12" by the custom class I created but it seems I'm unable to access subcollection.

Comment: Please post code you have tried.

Comment: Instead of describing how you database looks like, please add a screenshot of it.
 Please also responde with @AlexMamo